# Are those Ground (inertial) or Body frame points about which torque is calculated?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

[Choosing the reference axis in rotational mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/328513/297949) referring to this stack link, here the first answer tells that its not always that torque is equal to change of angular momentum, my doubt was do we take points lying on the body and moving with some acc, velocity for torque calculation about that point? Or the inertial ground frame which is at rest but lying on those body points?

Comment: Is there something more detail i need to add?

Comment: No, it is suffiient.

Comment: Ok, so any help?